# Convert table html to datatables jquery

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery

I have an table and I must to transform it in a "dataTables jQuery" format (tbody, thead...) and I don't know how to do, if possible with jQuery.

This is my table generated (note: this is a return of string method in C# return in a string writer):

```
<table cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
    <tbody><tr>

    </tr><tr>
        <td>426</td><td>05/06/2014 10:14:21</td><td>119870</td><td>Arquivos reunião</td><td>CONTRATO</td><td>VICTOR VASCONCELOS DE AQUINO</td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td>436</td><td>10/06/2014 11:47:29</td><td>119870</td><td>Arquivo Mapp</td><td>CONTRATO</td><td>VICTOR VASCONCELOS DE AQUINO</td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td>416</td><td>04/06/2014 14:50:07</td><td>119870</td><td>Multiplos arquivos</td><td>CONTRATO</td><td>VICTOR VASCONCELOS DE AQUINO</td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td>434</td><td>06/06/2014 14:11:25</td><td>119870</td><td>Contrato 2</td><td>CONTRATO</td><td>VICTOR VASCONCELOS DE AQUINO</td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td>419</td><td>04/06/2014 14:57:20</td><td>119870</td><td>Multiplos arquivos Mapp</td><td>CONVENIO</td><td>VICTOR VASCONCELOS DE AQUINO</td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td>444</td><td>18/06/2014 11:18:47</td><td>119870</td><td>documento</td><td>LICITAÇÃO</td><td>VICTOR VASCONCELOS DE AQUINO</td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td>441</td><td>18/06/2014 09:55:31</td><td>119870</td><td>Teste</td><td>LICITAÇÃO</td><td>VICTOR VASCONCELOS DE AQUINO</td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td>443</td><td>18/06/2014 10:49:08</td><td>119870</td><td>Material</td><td>LICITAÇÃO</td><td>VICTOR VASCONCELOS DE AQUINO</td>
    </tr>
</tbody></table>
```

Comment: Could you show what the output should look like? What is a "dataTables jQuery"

Comment: you can use dataTables on a HTML table likt this [http://www.datatables.net/examples/basic_init/zero_configuration.html](http://www.datatables.net/examples/basic_init/zero_configuration.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to add the thead to the table using jQuery, you would do something like this:

```
$('table tbody').before('<thead></thead>');
```